# Is this linear mapping positive definite, symmetric, bilinear?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

$V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and let be$s:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2} $ and $ s(x,y)=2x_1y_2+2x_2y_2$

Well I found out that the matrix is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

i) It's clear that the matrix is not positive definite

ii) It's is also easy to show that the matrix is not symmetric

iii) But how can I see that $s$ is a bilinear form? Is there probably an easy way to see it? I'm struggling to use the definition. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word bilinear has to to with the form: $s(x,y) = xAy^T$, where $x = (x_1,y_1)$, $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, y = (x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: so does it mean that this is bilinear, am I right?

Comment: Yes it is already bilinear but you have to write it correctly.